# JavaScript Conditionals not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm sorry I didn't search for another topic I thought this was a bit too specific, ok now that's out of the way!

When this is run missionButton.click(); is always ran, even though CheckHealth() is = to 0 it's like it's just skipping over the original if statement, is this normal for JavaScript (I'm used to other languages)

```
//__Action_Functions__

// When you're at zero health.
function Hospital(){     
    location.assign("http://www.gangwarsmobile.com/index.php?p=hospital");
    var HospitalUse = HospitalID;
    HospitalUse.click();

    setTimeout(location.assign("http://www.gangwarsmobile.com/index.php?p=crimes"),5000);
}


//__Does Mission__
function start(){
    var missionButton = CrimeID; //CrimeID is the ButtonID from the /crimes page/ variables at the top of this script.  

    if(CheckHealth() === 0){Hospital();}
    else if (CheckStamina() > 0);{missionButton.click();}
}
```

I can't see a reason why this will not work.

EXTRA

I'm using TamperMonkey, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Show your CheckHealth() function. It depends on what returns from CheckHealth()

Comment: It returns 0 like it should with 0 health, i added an alert function to make sure hours ago but it's still not even doing anything other then skipping over that, it does return 0 though.

Comment: have you tried if(CheckHealth() == 0) [double equal to]

Comment: So, i used what shadow had made, then it still didn't change, it has something to do with that Hospital function because i swapped it with 
location.assign("http://www.gangwarsmobile.com/index.php?p=hospital");
and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

Did you forget to take out **;** after the **() > 0** ?

Original:

```
if(CheckHealth() === 0){Hospital();}
else if (CheckStamina() > 0);{missionButton.click();}
```

Fixed:

```
if(CheckHealth() === 0){
    Hospital();
} else if (CheckStamina() > 0) {
    missionButton.click();
}
```

Comment: Fixed it, I had the extra location.assign in the hospital to go back, but apparently the way this was made i don't need to and it just goes back by it self.